# Intellij takes 5-10 minutes to move to next step while debugging

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

I am working on an automation project using selenium. I run my test using JUnit. It works well when just run the test. But while debugging Intellij hangs and it takes 5-10 minutes to move to next step.

I have tried following things to fix it but no luck so far.

- Disabled "Enable toString object view:"
- Added  localhost in hosts file.
- Disabled all Method breakpoints.

I created a `public static void main(String args[])` class and tried debugging it works fine with main class. But not with selenium.

I am using WebDriver 3.0.4

Thread dump

```
2017-06-22 20:01:45
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode):

"Exec Stream Pumper" #16 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000181e4000 nid=0x1588 runnable [0x00000000199ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:233)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Exec Stream Pumper" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000181ee000 nid=0x2794 runnable [0x00000000198ee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x00000000eca3d988> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Exec Default Executor" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000181f1000 nid=0x3704 runnable [0x00000000197ee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitForInterruptibly(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(ProcessImpl.java:449)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:364)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.access$200(DefaultExecutor.java:48)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor$1.run(DefaultExecutor.java:200)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" #12 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000152be800 nid=0x3540 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread2" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000015292000 nid=0x203c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread1" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000015291800 nid=0x1b34 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000015298000 nid=0x3060 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"JDWP Command Reader" #8 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001527f000 nid=0x1f64 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"JDWP Event Helper Thread" #7 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001527b800 nid=0x1560 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" #6 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001526e000 nid=0x1820 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000015262800 nid=0x18d8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000015261800 nid=0x2750 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x0000000015248800 nid=0x33e0 in Object.wait() [0x00000000165bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000eca82880> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x00000000eca82880> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000002c66000 nid=0x2d4c in Object.wait() [0x00000000164bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000eca828b0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x00000000eca828b0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Forwarding findElements on session f488352b-7233-4034-bc59-c502fe6f7682 to remote" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002b76000 nid=0x29e8 runnable [0x0000000002b6b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:437)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElements(By.java:356)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:398)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElements(DefaultElementLocator.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementListHandler.invoke(LocatingElementListHandler.java:36)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.isEmpty(Unknown Source)
    at assignment.automation.pages.HomePage.clickSignIn(HomePage.java:312)
    at assignment.automation.RegressionPackStep.MyWalletStepDef.iAmLoggedInToTHLWithAndOnHomePage(MyWalletStepDef.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.runBackground(CucumberScenario.java:59)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:42)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000015227000 nid=0x2440 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002b8c000 nid=0x2e44 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002b8d800 nid=0x1e8c runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002b8f000 nid=0xff8 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002b90800 nid=0x37fc runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000016d3e800 nid=0x15dc waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 10747
```

Comment: Try getting the thread dumps of the remote process you are debugging using `jstack` to see why it hangs during debug.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have updated my question not sure if that helps.

Comment: That doesn't looks like a relevant thread.

Comment: @CrazyCoder please check now.

Comment: Does IDE hang so that you can't use it, can't type in the editor, etc when stepping? If not, you are getting the dump from the wrong process, the point is to see what the target JVM you are debugging is doing, not IntelliJ IDEA. So, you have to invoke `jstack` on the **target** process, not IDE process.

Comment: @CrazyCoder No IDE works fine. It shows "waiting untill last debugger command completes". I pulled thread dump using jstack.

Comment: Try disabling alternate view for Collection classes. Also disable Watch method return values option in the Debugger tool window. Getting the [debugger logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241125) may also help to find why it's slow.